# Can SBT scopes be used for custom libraryDependencies for specific code blocks?

Tags: scala, hadoop, cassandra, sbt

I've a simple SBT project, in which one code block reads from HDFS (needs a certain version of Hadoop's `libraryDependencies`) and another code block (needs another version of Hadoop's `libraryDependencies`) writes the filtered result to Cassandra.

Can [SBT scopes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Scopes.html) be used to assign a different `libraryDependencies` to the two code blocks?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but you have to split your code over one of the scope axises: Project, configuration, task. The only axis that can be used for your purpose is the "project" axis. So you have to create a [multi-project sbt project](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html) and split your code on its sub projects.

But his will **not** solve your problem. Because you will not be able to run the resulting application. The Java class loader has no way to decide, when to use the one version of Hadoop and when the other. It will load one version of the classes in question and then use it in all cases.

For this task you have to use a context aware class loader. An example for this is an [OSGi container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi#Architecture), like [Apache Feilx](http://felix.apache.org/). OSGi is version aware and can load different versions of the same library in the same Java process. It will then reference to the classes of the correct version of the library depending on the context the library is used.

To be more precise: You must convert your different versions of your Hadoop library into OSGi bundles. Then you must split your code into mutliple OSGi bundles, each with a dependency of the correct version of the Hadoop bundle in its meta data (Manifest file). When you want to start you application, you must run it in an OSGi container.

This can be done, but is quite complex. Better to clean up your code, so you only depend on one version of the Hadoop library.